# How to make bubbles and FAB like Facebook messenger in android

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi I need simple help from an android programmers
I've seen Facebook Messenger and noticed the chat icon that stays in the screen when you open any other application . 
I want to do one like her but it's as simple, When the user clicks on it, it shows some other icons such as Float action button.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can start customizing [this library](https://github.com/henrychuangtw/Android-ChatHead), which aims to provide a similar experience to the Facebook bubble chat.

You can replace the drawing code with yours, or use an XML to inflate a view based on your needs.

Comment: Well, I'll try it out